# loading local fonts with font face observer - every weight needed in my promise?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I've got 2 local fonts each with 2 styles (normal and bold) that I want to use on a site and I'm trying to set up font face observer to load them. I have listed both fonts with the same name so that the browser can chose normal vs bold without me having to touch every bit of css to set a specific font for bold. I think normally this should work fine but with the addition of font face observer I'm not sure if I now need to specify the weight and then amend my css accordingly. I read on https://github.com/bramstein/fontfaceobserver that font weight is not mandatory but will be set to "normal" if not specified.

So this:

```
    var fontHeading = new FontFaceObserver("Oxygen", { weight: 400 });
    var fontMain = new FontFaceObserver("Rubik", { weight: 400 });
    Promise.all([
      fontHeading.load(),
      fontMain.load(),
    ]).then(function() {
    document.documentElement.className += " fonts-loaded";
    });
```

Or this:

```
var fontHeading = new FontFaceObserver("Oxygen", { weight: 400 });
var fontHeadingBold = new FontFaceObserver("Oxygen", { weight: 700 });
var fontMain = new FontFaceObserver("Rubik", { weight: 400 });
var fontMainBold = new FontFaceObserver("Rubik", { weight: 700 });
Promise.all([
    fontHeading.load(),
    fontHeadingBold.load(),
    fontMain.load(),
    fontMainBold.load(),
]).then(function() {
    document.documentElement.className += " fonts-loaded";
});
```

my css:

```
 @font-face {
      font-family: 'Rubik';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src:
        url(../fonts/rubik-v6-latin-regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../fonts/rubik-v6-latin-regular.woff) format('woff');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Rubik';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      src:
        url(../fonts/rubik-v6-latin-700.woff2) format('woff2'),
        url(../fonts/rubik-v6-latin-700.woff) format('woff');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Oxygen';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 400;
      src:
        url(../fonts/oxygen-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
        url(../fonts/oxygen-webfont.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Oxygen';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 700;
      src:
        url(../fonts/oxygen-bold-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
        url(../fonts/oxygen-bold-webfont.woff2) format('woff2');
    }
```

css:

```
h3 { 
font-weight: bold;
font-family: "oxygen-bold";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `font-family: "oxygen-bold";` when you've told CSS what to do for the family "Oxygen" at two different weights?

You specified what it should do for weights 400 and 700, so just use that:

```
h3 { 
  font-family: Oxygen; /* no quotes needed when there are no spaces/dashes/etc */
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need use the same name of font-family:

In font-face:

```
    @font-face {
          font-family: 'Oxygen';
          font-style: normal;
          font-weight: 700;
          src:
            url(../fonts/oxygen-bold-webfont.woff) format('woff'),
            url(../fonts/oxygen-bold-webfont.woff2) format('woff2');
        }
```

in css:

```
h3 {
 font-family: 'Oxygen';
}
```